# Como colocar un logo en el encabezado de un informe en Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

Estoy generando varios informes en Rmardown y lo tengo listo, ahora quiero agregar un logo de la empresa en la parte superior derecha y estoy teniendo dificultades.

Pongo lo que tengo al momento y lo mas cercano que he logrado :
La salida del archivo es un PDF

```
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: pdflatex
tables: true
params:
  n_canton: 1
  imagen: NULL
  
header-includes:
 \usepackage{booktabs}
 \usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{array}
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{wrapfig}
 \usepackage{float}
 \usepackage{pdflscape}
 \usepackage{tabu}
 \usepackage{threeparttable}
 \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \setlength\headheight{20pt}
 \fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{Logo.png}}
 \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{GPIM}
```

He usado `Fancy` porque es el que mejor resultado me dio de todos, pero con dar con una solución me da igual que usar.

`Resultado:`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No logro que el logo quede en la parte superior derecha y **SOLO** en la primer pagina, y no en todas como me pasa ahora. Tampoco entiendo porque se repite mi primer parrafo (CANTON LOTE MONTE) al agregar la imagen.

He revisado en bastantes post del foro y no logro una solución.

Alguna sugerencia? Gracias un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente hay formas mejores de resolverlo, pero al menos está, es bastante sencilla y pareciera lograr el objetivo: 1) logo alineado a izquierda y solo en la primer página 2) siguiente renglón ya con el título alineado al centro

```
header-includes:
  \usepackage{titling}
  \pretitle{
    \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{logo.png}
    \hfill
    \text{}
    \\[\bigskipamount]
  }
  \posttitle{\end{center}}
```

Comment: @particio-moracho que tal? Gracias por responder, con tu respuesta no me añade el logo, ni hace nada, probé con y sin comillas en la dirección del logo pero nada. Sera algún problema de identación o de escritura? En mi ```YAML``` no tengo ```Title```, eso sera algún inconveniente? Aclaro nuevamente que la salida es PDF. Un saludo

Comment: Hola Rodrigo, el código lo probé con un esqueleto super básico de Rmd, habría que ver como se comporta si tienes otras configuraciones de latex en tu archivo. Revisa por las dudas que escribí `logo.png` y en tu caso pareciera ser `Logo.png`, si estás en Linux o MAC es un detalle importante

Comment: Hola Patricio, es raro, porque no tengo otra cosa que la que ves en el YAML de arriba en el  post, seguiré intentando. Trabajo en windows, otra forma que pensé (que no es la ideal) es colocar una imagen en un ```chunk```arriba del todo y comenzar mi pdf mas abajo.

Comment: Combiné el código de tu pregunta con el que te acabo de pasar y me estaría funcionando adecuadamente, podes mirarlo online: https://rstudio.cloud/project/2883099, cualquier cosa decime.

Comment: Si no tenés cuenta en Rstudio cloud, podes crearte una que es gratuita. El código de prueba sino es este: https://pastebin.com/8QVxX5g5